# dnSpy not showing locals after hitting breakpoint

Tags: .net, dnspy

I'm trying to debug .NET app DLL. I'm attaching to the process, open DLL module from memory and I'm setting the breakpoint inside of DLL. After hitiing the breakpoint dnSpy didn't show Locals and I can't step through the code. Why is it like that?

Comment: Which dnspy version you've used?

Comment: I'm using latest version 1.6.8. Binary is protected by Themida. I'm injecting scylla and attaching to it.
In the meantime I've made a dump from memory and I have noticed that this binary is also protected by Smart Assembly. Anyway I can't run it after dump.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your binary is protected using proxy objects.

Proxy objects usually implement and provide obscure debugging information (and/or methods) that interferes dnSpy's or other debuggers' initiative to display locals and other useful information. For more info look [here](https://blog.washi.dev/posts/debugger-proxy-objects/).

Note that it's not guaranteed for this method to be the cause, but for me it was the most frequent case.